# about a way to change default global planner

Tags: ros, base-global-planner, eband-local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
Everyone might think that this question is same as this article ( http://answers.ros.org/question/39347/how-to-change-global-planner-of-move_base/ ). Actually, as following the answer, I edited my move_base.launch.xml like this.

```
<node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" respawn="false" name="move_base" output="screen">
 <param name="base_global_planner" value="carrot_planner/CarrotPlanner" />  
 <rosparam file="$(find turtlebot_navigation)/param/move_base_params.yaml" command="load" />
 &ltrosparam file="$(find turtlebot_navigation)/param/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="global_costmap" />
 <rosparam file="$(find turtlebot_navigation)/param/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="local_costmap" />
 &ltrosparam file="$(find turtlebot_navigation)/param/local_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
 <rosparam file="$(find turtlebot_navigation)/param/global_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
 &ltrosparam file="$(find turtlebot_navigation)/param/eband_planner_params.yaml" command="load" />
 <param name="base_local_planner" value="eband_local_planner/EBandPlannerROS" />
 <param name="global_costmap/map_topic" value="$(arg map_topic)" />
 <remap from="cmd_vel" to="navigation_velocity_smoother/raw_cmd_vel"/>
</node>
```

The result is following. As showing, Global plan set to elastic band. Elastic band is a local planner, not a global planner.
My experiment environment is a turtlebot2 as a target, Hydro as ROS dist on Ubuntu 12.04.

```
 [ INFO] [1397253785.373263757]: Global plan set to elastic band for optimization
 [ INFO] [1397253785.374082648]: TrajectoryController: Goal reached with distance 0.00, 0.11 (od = -0.02); sending zero velocity
```

Could anybody tell me some information to change a global planner? Thank you in advance!

I show you an additional information. Rviz just seems to display a eband_local_planner as global & local planner.
[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/152196/about-a-way-to-change-default-global-planner/) by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 894 on 2014-04-11

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on 2014-04-11**:
I should have read this article on this web ( http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/Writing%20A%20Global%20Path%20Planner%20As%20Plugin%20in%20ROS)

**Comment by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on 2014-04-11**:
The reason that another planner isn't displayed on Rviz relate to yaml file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The answer on this site ( http://answers.ros.org/question/39347/how-to-change-global-planner-of-move_base/ ) is correct.
It's just adding the following code to move_base.launch.xml

```
< param name="base_global_planner" value="carrot_planner/CarrotPlanner" />
```

A way to check a change of planner is to use this command  `rostopic echo /move_base/parameter_updates`
,but the problem of a topic in  Global_Plan and Local_Plan on Rviz remains unsolved.

---

Originally posted by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) with karma: 894 on 2014-04-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hubery524](https://answers.ros.org/users/46310/hubery524/) on 2019-12-11**:
when I use the CarrotPlanner, there is no error,;But in rviz move_base, there is no CarrotPlanner,do you encounter this problem?